# Cluster validation and kriging interpolation in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, kriging, silhouette, geostatistics

I am stuck with the kriging interpolation analysis and colour-coding the silhouette output for correct representation of clusters. Any assistance in this regard is greatly appreciated

For the kriging, I don't know how to proceed on this. For the cluster validation, I did the cluster analysis using hkmeans, but the cluster validation output swapped the colours for the cluster

Comment: Could you please share some code you have tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Quinten. For the cluster validation, this is what I have tried: Nig.diana <- diana(Nig, stand = FALSE, keep.diss=TRUE)

names(Nig.diana)

Nig.diss <- Nig.diana$diss

head(Nig.diss)

Nigsil <- silhouette(Nig_hkm_k4$cluster, Nig.diss)

fviz_silhouette(Nigsil, label = F, print.summary = T)